# SQL Server Escape an Underscore

Tags: sql-server

How do I escape the underscore character?

I am writing something like the following where clause and want to be able to find actual entries with _d at the end.

```
Where Username Like '%_d'
```

Answer (score 724, accepted):

[T-SQL Reference for LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals):

> You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets. The following table shows several examples of using the LIKE keyword and the [ ] wildcard characters.

For your case:

```
... LIKE '%[_]d'
```

Answer (score 262):

Obviously @Lasse solution is right, but there's another way to solve your problem: T-SQL operator `LIKE` defines the optional [ESCAPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) clause, that lets you declare a character which will escape the next character into the pattern.

For your case, the following WHERE clauses are equivalent:

```
WHERE username LIKE '%[_]d';            -- @Lasse solution
WHERE username LIKE '%$_d' ESCAPE '$';
WHERE username LIKE '%^_d' ESCAPE '^';
```

Comment: To complete the picture: the `ESCAPE` clause is part of the SQL standard and will work on any DBMS, not just SQL Server.

Answer (score 9):

These solutions totally make sense. Unfortunately, neither worked for me as expected. Instead of trying to hassle with it, I went with a work around:

```
select *
from information_schema.columns 
where replace(table_name,'_','!') not like '%!%'
order by table_name
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding `[ ]` did the job for me

```
like '%[\\_]%'
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue using like pattern `'%_%'` did not work - as the question indicates :-)

Using `'%\_%'` did not work either as this first `\` is interpreted "before the like".

Using `'%\\_%'` works. The `\\` (double backslash) is first converted to single `\` (backslash) and then used in the like pattern.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, just use the escape
`'%\_%'`

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [Gerardo Lima's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10415670/12221876), I was having problems when trying to use backslash as my escape character for the ESCAPE clause. This caused issues:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email LIKE '%@%\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

It was resolved by switching to an exclamation point. This worked:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email LIKE '%@%!_%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these worked for me in SSIS v18.0, so I would up doing something like this:
`WHERE CHARINDEX('_', thingyoursearching) < 1`
..where I am trying to ignore strings with an underscore in them. If you want to find things that have an underscore, just flip it around:
`WHERE CHARINDEX('_', thingyoursearching) > 0`