# Escape Character in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, escaping, char

I want to use quotation with escape character. How can I do to avoid the following error when one has a special character?

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string.

Comment: Can you please **show** us the query??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

To escape `'` you simly need to put another before: `''`

As the second answer shows it's possible to escape single quote like this:

```
select 'it''s escaped'
```

result will be

```
it's escaped
```

If you're concatenating SQL into a VARCHAR to execute (i.e. dynamic SQL), then I'd recommend parameterising the SQL. This has the benefit of helping guard against SQL injection plus means you don't have to worry about escaping quotes like this (which you do by doubling up the quotes).

e.g. instead of doing

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Field1 = ''AAA'''
EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

try this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Field1 = @Field1'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Field1 VARCHAR(10)', 'AAA'
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @PeterMoore Either the OP would have used the 1st part of my answer (doubling up the quotes, as per other answers below), or would have used the preferred approach I recommended for building up a SQL query in a string variable - to use parameterized SQL. Either way, both are answers to the question

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Sometimes user need ODBC connection which means you can only use pure SQL.

Comment: Edited answer to more it more clear and better fit the question

Answer (score 185):

You can escape quotation like this:

```
select 'it''s escaped'
```

result will be

```
it's escaped
```

Answer (score 65):

You can define your escape character, but you can only use it with a `LIKE` clause.

Example:

```
SELECT columns FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Here it will search for `%` in whole string and this is how one can use `ESCAPE` identifier in `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 25):

You need to just replace `'` with `''` inside your string

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM tableD
WHERE colA = 'John''s Mobile'
```

You can also use `REPLACE(@name, '''', '''''')` if generating the SQL dynamically

If you want to escape inside a like statement then you need to use the ESCAPE syntax

It's also worth mentioning that you're leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks if you don't consider it. More info at Google or: http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/How_do_I_escape_single_quotes_in_SQL_queries%3F

Comment: and yet answers by dugokontov or RichardPianka don't have any similar -1?

Comment: @MichaelMunsey try it for yourself: `select '` returns the error `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''`. Nowhere in my answer do I use `"` only two `'`, not sure why mine is the only answer with down votes.

Answer (score 15):

Escaping quotes in MSSQL is done by a double quote, so a `''` or a `""` will produce one escaped `'` and `"`, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE username LIKE '%[_]d';            -- @Lasse solution
WHERE username LIKE '%$_d' ESCAPE '$';
WHERE username LIKE '%^_d' ESCAPE '^';
```

FROM:
[SQL Server Escape an Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821/sql-server-escape-an-underscore)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to escape user input in a variable you can do  like below within SQL

```
  Set @userinput = replace(@userinput,'''','''''')
```

The @userinput will be now escaped with an extra single quote for every occurance of a quote

Answer (score -1):

To keep the code easy to read, you can use square brackets `[]` to quote the string containing `'` or vice versa .

Comment: This is incorrect.  Brackets work on illegal characters in field, table, or schema names.

Comment: Yeah, you right, its for the object names, not string contents. I must read the question wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `**\**` character before the value you want to escape e.g
`insert into msglog(recipient) values('Mr. O\'riely')`
`select * from msglog where recipient = 'Mr. O\'riely'`