# Escape SQL string in Business One

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

How do I escape a string coming from the user in BusinessOne? I have seen some examples (in the official samples!) that seem sensible to SQL injection:

```
SAPbobsCOM.Recordset RecSet = ( ( SAPbobsCOM.Recordset )( oCompany.GetBusinessObject( SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset ) ) ); 
string QryStr = "update [@VIDS] set U_RENTED = 'Y', U_CARDCODE = '" + CardStr + "' where Code = '" + MovieStr + "'"; 
            RecSet.DoQuery( QryStr );
RecSet.DoQuery( QryStr );
```

Is there a way to avoid SQL injection with simple SQL queries (without stored procedures)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the DI-API does not provide prepared statements therefore you need to secure your inputs manually. Research one how this can be done is contained in the [How to escape value in MSSQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477126/escape-value-in-mssql-server-with-java) question:

> After reading [New SQL Truncation Attacks And How To Avoid Them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163523.aspx) it *seems* sufficient to escape identifiers using `[` (and doubling each occurrence of `]`) and values using `'` (again doubling every occurence of `'`). A hint to a library whose concern is correct escaping of MSSQL would be nice nevertheless.

I'm using the following Java code to escape identifiers and values (porting to different languages should be trivial):

## Quoting identifiers

```
public static String identifier(final CharSequence identifier) {
    final int length = identifier.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 + length * 2);

    sb.append('[');

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        char c = identifier.charAt(i);

        if (']' == c) {
            sb.append(']');
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }
    sb.append(']');

    return sb.toString();
}
```

## Quoting values

```
public static String value(final CharSequence value) {
    final int length = value.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 + length * 2);

    sb.append('\'');

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        char c = value.charAt(i);

        if ('\'' == c) {
            sb.append('\'');
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }
    sb.append('\'');

    return sb.toString();
}
```