# How to add a single quote when I have single quote in PHP for SQL Management studio

Tags: php, sql-server, regex

I am having trouble with SQL Management studio and I do not want to connect to this SQL server I want to make the data ready for my lines to be inserted in this database
I have a text file with the lines of strings that I want to insert in sql server the line is like this:

`You're Doing It Wrong!!,Mike Walsh,Intermediate`

So it should be like this to be ready for sql server.

`You''re Doing It Wrong!!,Mike Walsh,Intermediate`

I also have this in lines:

`Never Have to Say "Mayday!!!" Again`

Is this one going to become a problem? Should I have any plan for it also?

I tried to use addslash and then replace the slash with the a single quote by doing:

```
  $str=",('".addslashes ($array[0])."')";
     $str=str_replace("\\","\'",$str);
     echo $str;
```

I did the comma and parenthesis for when I have insert to query in sql server
the result of this one will be:

```
    ,('You\''re Doing It Wrong!!'),
,('Never Have to Say \'"Mayday!!!\'" Again'),
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Use prepared statements to insert your data.

Comment: I'm not using mysql and I am just making ready my lines to be inserted in sql server

Comment: My comment says nothing about mysql. Use the PDO driver and insert your data with a prepared statement, query separated from data.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what the question is: would you like to know which characters need to be escaped or do you have problems with the regexp creating them? For the escape sequences, you might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139770/escape-character-in-sql-server .

Comment: I don't want to do that, it is not a tremendous data and also if I even want I can't database is remote

Comment: @lambda.xy.x I am she by the way, I want to have a regex that can handle the string for sql management studio , I wanted to add a single quote to the singe quote and as I said I have problem with that

Comment: If you're doing it in the sql management studio than you're not using PHP.

Comment: @chris85 data is for sql server and I am just playing with php in text file making it clean to go to sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using prepared statements is the best way. If you insist on a regex way, you can double single quotes with `preg_replace` so that there is an even number of consequent single quotes:

```
''|(')
```

And replace with `''`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tO5lG3/5)

Sample PHP code:

```
$re = "/''|(')/"; 
$str = "You're Doing It Wrong!!,'''Mike Walsh'',Intermediate"; 
$subst = "''"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Output:

```
You''re Doing It Wrong!!,''''Mike Walsh'',Intermediate
```

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching this problem in a wrong way: rather than preparing the string to be "pasted" into SQL Server's query, *parameterize* your SQL, and pass the string as a parameter. This way you wouldn't have to escape it at all, and the number of quotes or other special characters wouldn't matter either:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable(id,name) VALUES (?,?)"
$params = array($someId, $name)
$sql_srv_query($db_conn, $sql, $params);
```

Comment: I cannot use sql server I am having remote access and I cannot do it other way

Comment: @Nickparsa The nice thing about parameterized queries is that it's very much bulletproof. You should try using prepared statement over a file, unless it's a one-time job. Missing a single corner case while generating "canned" SQL can be extremely costly, especially if someone with bad intentions and a good knowledge of your script has access to your source text file.

Comment: It is not a serious issue really, it is just a project which our professor sent us some data in a really bad format of excel sheet with so many typos and wrong stuff and it is not even related to the project we should only have this data.

Answer (score 0):

May be try this

```
$str = "You're Doing \"It Wrong!!,Mike Walsh,Intermediate";
$st = addslashes($str);
```

First of all you can replace " with \", then make `addslashes`

Comment: Mssql doesn't escape with slashes.