# Line Breaks with ' and "

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am using phonegap for my mobile application . I need to generate queries dynamically and then execute the query;

```
qry += "('" + item1 + "','" + id + "','" + item2 + "','" + item3 + "'),";
```

item1,item2,item3 should be strings so that query happens successfully while executing.

the above bit of is fine for my use case in most of the cases . But i got an unexpected error now .

If the value from item1 is as `1'Feet` or `10 ' Feet` code breaks and execution fails .

How can i overcome this ?

Comment: By escaping the string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ES2015 solution to show off template tags:

```
function esc(pieces, ...subs) {
    var result = pieces[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; ++i) {
        // uses `.escape`, use other escaping function if you want.
        // for example with `/`
        result += escape(subs[i]) + pieces[i + 1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Template tags give us custom logic for templating in the new ES2015 standard and are very useful for this thing.

```
var hello = "9'c"
console.log(esc`(${hello})`); // (9%27c)
```

```js
function esc(pieces) {
    var result = pieces[0];
    var subs = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; ++i) {
        result += escape(subs[i]) + pieces[i + 1];
    }
    return result;
}
var hello = "9'c";


document.body.innerHTML = esc`(${hello})`;
```

Answer (score 0):

At last found answer  , We need escape string in Sql rather than in jquery , replacing double single quotes instead of an single quote solves the problem .

```
item1.replace(/'/g, "''") ;
```

[Escape Character in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139770/escape-character-in-sql-server)

Comment: you should have mentioned in your question that the query goes to MySQL

Comment: Yea i forgot that one !

Answer (score -2):

[Edited the previous answer]

Try this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function fnEscapeQuotes(){
    var item1= "Ford's";
    var item2= "Dodges's";
    var item3= "Benz's";
    var id=100;
    var qry = "('" + item1 + "','" + id + "','" + item2 + "','" + item3 + "'),";
    alert(JSON.stringify(qry).slice(1, -1));
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="fnEscapeQuotes();">
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On this querying is done succesfully . But in db i get #39 instead of ' .

Comment: It's building a javascript string.  It needs to be javascript-escaped (with `\'`), not HTML escaped.

Comment: How can i escape it with \n if the value for the variable is assigned dynamically ?