# SQL Server SQL query to escape the closing square bracket ]

Tags: sql-server

I have db whose name is shreyanshdb] that is it has a closing square bracket.
I wanted to perform the backup of this db using SQL query in SQL server.
But it is throwing me an exception: Transact-sql exception.

Here is the command :
 **BACKUP DATABASE [shreyanshdb]] to disk = 'c:\DB'**

I really don't know how do i escape the closing square bracket...

Comment: Should google "ms sql escape character", [first hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139770/escape-character-in-sql-server). Not sure if it'll help you, but at least show us what you did try. Flagging question as unclear.

Comment: Nothing helpful to add but fascinated to know how the DB got that name and why you can't change it to something less problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use sp_executesql for this. Where you pass the databasename as a parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: In SQL server it actually worked with the following command:  BACKUP DATABASE "shreyanshdb]" TO DISK = 'D:\LOG_DIR'  . How come it worked with double quotes.... Actually i have to execute or write this SQL command in c sharp...so should i append double quotes in the db name...

Answer (score 1):

```
BACKUP DATABASE [shreyanshdb]]] to disk = 'c:\DB'
```

You can see how things should be quoted from the [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) function documentation. For rectangular brackets, the closing bracket should be doubled.

It's probably best not to use those brackets, or spaces, or any irregular characters in a database name, table name, column name or any other object name in SQL Server.