# Variable not working in IF NOT EXISTS .. CREATE TABLE query, and I have no idea why

Tags: sql, database, azure

I'm using Azure SQL Database (T-SQL), and having problems with a "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" query.  I've already read the links here, and probably a few others:

- [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)
- [Escape Character in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139770/escape-character-in-sql-server)

My code:

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(max);
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max);
SET @tableName = 'Russ';
SET @sqlquery = 'if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name=' + @tableName + 'and xtype=''U'') create table ' + @tableName + '([ID] [bigint] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.standardsequence), [Name One] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL, [Name Two] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL)';
exec sp_executesql @sqlquery;
```

- Error I'm getting is "Syntax error near xtype='U'", but I've escaped that part so I don't understand the problem there.
- Every place says to use sp_executesql, which I'm doing.  I also tried setting the variable in the sp_executesql statement (ex: EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@tableName VARCHAR(10)', 'Russ'), but it doesn't work that way either.
- Query works perfectly fine without variables, so I'm pretty sure the problem is with that, but just don't know why.

What am I doing wrong?  I am stumped.  If there was a Stumped Bureau, they'd declare me officially stumped.

Comment: Please remove `if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name=' + @tableName + 'and xtype=''U'') create table ' + @tableName + '([ID] [bigint] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.standardsequence), [Name One] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL, [Name Two] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL)` in your query `xtype` to `type`

Comment: You can't use PRINT in Azure SQL editor, just FYI.  Probably wouldn't have had a problem if I could.

Comment: Thanks, man for sharing the knowledge :)

Comment: @jishansiddique I didn't see what you said a few days ago, but this makes me curious and interested - Why change "xtype" to just "type"?   This didn't solve my problem, but just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table name` is not properly terminated, additional quotes will fix it.

but, its a good practice to add `begin` and `end` when using conditional statements in `sql`

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(max);
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max);
SET @tableName = 'Russ';
SET @sqlquery = 'if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name=''' + @tableName + ''' and xtype=''U'') 
    begin 
        create table ' + @tableName + '([ID] [bigint] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.standardsequence), [Name One] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL, [Name Two] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL) 
    end';

exec sp_executesql @sqlquery;
```