# SQL Select Query with a clause NOT CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to make a query witch select only field doesn't contains the percent symbol "%".

this field takes values like 1, 1,5, 1,5%. I want select only 1 and 1,5 in this example.

my query is :

```
SELECT * FROM CommissionContract 
WHERE commission DOESN'T CONTAINS THE SYMBOL "%"
```

Comment: I'm using sql server.

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14518639/6794089

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape Character in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139770/escape-character-in-sql-server)

Comment: Ref: [Pattern Matching with the ESCAPE Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the operator `NOT LIKE` to exclude the values that contain the char `'%'`

```
SELECT * FROM CommissionContract 
WHERE commission NOT LIKE '%[%]%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1ecf8b9a93607de150378aac4a54d4a4).

Answer (score 0):

try with `not like`

```
SELECT * FROM CommissionContract 
WHERE commission NOT LIKE '%[%]%'
```

Comment: it doesn't accept - " - symbol, if I change it to  - ' -  it selects all the data.

Comment: @amine try now.