# How can three double quotes ''' work in a mybatis @Insert annotated block?

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to use three double quotes """ in a mybatis @Insert annotated block
but IDEA shows there are errors, it says java 8 doesn't support this, but previously I remember in another project is supports, what is wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDlUC.png

[image]

Comment: So, what was the error? It should tell you the problem is. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139770/escape-character-in-sql-server

Comment: Text block should be enclosed by three 'double quotes' . See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).

Comment: @ave I tried, but it is not supported by java 8?

Comment: @lily Nope. Text block was added in 15. It was available in 13 and 14 as a preview feature, though.

Comment: For complex SQL statements should be written in the xml file