# How to select record having "_" in the field using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table Customers with below records:

```
CustomerID  CustomerName    Country
1           Alfr_eds        Germany
2           Ana             Mexico
3           Antonio         Mexico
```

And I need to select records containing `_` in the customer Name, so what query can be used.

I tried the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers where CustomerName LIKE '%_%';
```

But it returns all the data.

Comment: Okay? What's your question?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588455/use-underscore-character-in-wild-card-charecter-of-like-query-gives-me-all-table

Comment: The underscore is the wildcard in a `LIKE` query for one arbitrary character.
Hence LIKE `%_%` means "give me all records with at least one arbitrary character in this column".

Answer (score 3):

To "disable" the underscore as a wildcard, you need to escape it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
where CustomerName LIKE '%\_%' escape '\';
```

The clause `escape '\'` tells the database that any character after a `\` should not be treated as a wildcard. You can use any character you like, e.g. `#` would work just as well

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
where CustomerName LIKE '%#_%' escape '#';
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can use `[ ]` as a wildacard character, check [`LIKE (Transact-SQL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms179859(v=sql.120).aspx) documentation.

[image]

So you can write it like this:

```
select * from customers where customerName like '%[_]%'
```

Your query is using `_` wildcard character, so it basically checks if `customerName` has any single character in it.

Comment: Someone with your rep should know better than posting a code-only answer. Tut tut tut :)

Comment: Just curious, why do we have to include box parentheses ?

Comment: fixing this :) thanks for heads-up

Comment: @Marshal, other way it matches any one character. `[]` this is for Sql Server.

Comment: @RomanPekar, are you sure OP uses Sql Server?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri good point, I'll add it to my answer