# VSTS REST API Get ReleaseDefinition by name

Tags: rest, azure-devops, release-management

How do I get a release definition from the VSTS Rest API by release definition name?

the name query string parameter is ignored when I GET from

https://{instance}vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=4.0-preview.3&name={definition name}

I need a way to fetch the release when I don't know the release id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/definitions#get-a-list-of-release-definitions) you can use the *searchText* parameter:
*Optional. Get release definitions with names starting with searchText*

I quickly tried and it worked with this query:

```
https://{instance}vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=4.0-preview.3&searchText=definitionName
```

However if you would have multiple definitions starting with that string you might get back more than one definition.

**Edit:** I just saw that on top of that you can specify the *isExactNameMatch* parameter.
*'true'to gets the release definitions with exact match as specified in searchText. Default is 'false'.*

Comment: I guess I missed that in reading the docs.  That's for pointing that out.  Its far less intuitive than the build definition api.

Comment: In TFS 2018 U2, the searchText parameter is not filtering like documentation says it does (with parameter isExactNameMatch default/false). It seems to ignore underscores as far I can see, and it's more of a wildcard search than starts with… So searching for REL_ against expected name "Main_REL" it returns the definition. Searching for "REL_" and "\_REL\_" against that name also returns the definition. Searching for "RE_L" fails though. I think the underscore char in the searchText parameter gets converted to some weird character internally… Be advised ;)

Comment: AHA! To clarify my issue commented above: [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588455/why-does-using-an-underscore-character-in-a-like-filter-give-me-all-the-results)
The underscore is due to MSSQL LIKE keyword behavior. Therefore the searchText seems to be wildcard search indeed.