# Search '_' in SQL shows all records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query to search the name with '_', but it shows all records of the table. Would someone tell me what's wrong with my script. Thanks.

There is my SQL script:

```
declare @Name varchar(50)='_'
select *  FROM products WHERE  Name like @Name +'%'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does using an Underscore character in a LIKE filter give me all the results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588455/why-does-using-an-underscore-character-in-a-like-filter-give-me-all-the-results)

Comment: Knowing what DBMS the op is using would be helpful.

Comment: @JoeHartzell, can't the  <mysql> tag be trusted?

Comment: @JoeHartzell: The question is tagged MySQL. As it's the only DBMS tag, it would seem fairly apparent.

Comment: Missed that, sorry!

Comment: If your query works, then you are not using MySQL -- presumably the database is SQL Server.  Please tag correctly.

Comment: `where left(name, 1) = '_'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_` is a wildcard that matches any character.  You can choose another character to escape it.  Say:

```
WHERE Name like replace(@Name, '_', '$_') + '%' ESCAPE '$'
```

That can get cumbersome, so you can just use different logic:

```
WHERE LEFT(Name, LEN(@Name)) = @Name
```

Unfortunately, this formulation prevents the use of an index.

Comment: Side note: "Unfortunately, this formulation prevents the use of an index" You could make a generated column and index that column as a workaround if you are using MySQL 5.7+ to "support" expression/functional indexes (Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html )

Answer (score 0):

To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by the escape character. For example.

> \_ matches one _ character