# loop to add value in dynamic OR statement

Tags: sql-server

I broke this query down to the most basic. I need to add an OR statement dynamically, which includes a variable. I need to get any id and its corresponding id with an underscore. So, my resulting @SQL to execute would be:

```
create table #Test (OrganizationId varchar(100), OrigID varchar(50))
insert into #Test(OrganizationId,OrigID)
Values  ('5','31'),
        ('5','31_00000'),
        ('5','33'),
        ('5','33_00000'),
        ('5','25'),
        ('5','25_00000'),
        ('5','HD_00000'),
        ('5','HD')

-- 
DECLARE 
        @OrganizationId int = 5,
        @OriginId nvarchar(256) = N'31,25,33'




create table #inVars(id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, origins varchar(256))
  insert into #inVars(origins)
  Values ('31'),
         ('33'),
         ('25')

 DECLARE  @SQL           NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)


 SET @ParamDefinition = N'@OrganizationId int,
                        @OriginId nvarchar(256)'


SET @SQL= 'SELECT OrganizationId,OrigID
FROM #Test
WHERE OrganizationId=@OrganizationId'

IF ISNULL(@OriginId,'') <> ''
     SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND OrigID in (''' + @OriginId + ''') '
     DECLARE @counter INT = 1, @max INT = 0, @Origin nvarchar(50), @SQL_2 nvarchar(max)
     SELECT @max = COUNT(id) FROM #inVars
     WHILE @counter <= @max
     BEGIN
        SET @Origin = '_%'
        SET @Origin = (select origins from #invars where id = CAST(@counter as varchar(10))) + @Origin
        SET @SQL_2 = N' OR OrigID LIKE ''' + @Origin + ''' '
        SET @SQL_2 = @SQL + @SQL_2
print(@SQL_2)
        SET @counter = @counter + 1

    END

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_2,@ParamDefinition,@OrganizationId,@OriginId

drop table #inVars
drop table #Test
```

Here is how my query is executing now:

```
SELECT OrganizationId,OrigID
    FROM #Test
    WHERE OrganizationId=@OrganizationId AND OrigID in ('31,25,33')  OR OrigID LIKE '31_%' 
SELECT OrganizationId,OrigID
    FROM #Test
    WHERE OrganizationId=@OrganizationId AND OrigID in ('31,25,33')  OR OrigID LIKE '33_%' 
SELECT OrganizationId,OrigID
    FROM #Test
    WHERE OrganizationId=@OrganizationId AND OrigID in ('31,25,33')  OR OrigID LIKE '25_%'
```

This is my desired result:

```
SELECT OrganizationId,OrigID
    FROM #Test
    WHERE OrganizationId=@OrganizationId AND OrigID in ('31,25,33')  OR OrigID LIKE '31_%' 
    OR OrigID LIKE '33_%' 
    OR OrigID LIKE '25_%'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Just saying "it isn't working as expected" is not very helpful. We don't know what you are trying to do or what isn't working about it. I don't understand why you are using dynamic sql here. Can you try to explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure, sorry its my first post here. I am trying to insert a variable into a dynamic sql with an OR clause. This query is just a very small piece of my original uery. I was trying to make it small just to show my need. I need dynamic sql because I have about 7 other filters that are built dynamically depending on the values entered by the user. This origin id filter is just one of them. I need to be able to search a table for any Ids that the user enters, which in this case is 31,33,25 and their matching origin id with a trailing underscore(i.e. 31_, 25_,33_).

Comment: Add these details to your question. Comments are terrible for this as they get lost and the formatting is nonexistent.

Comment: For this type of catch all query you might consider using table valued parameters. Also, like uses the underscore as a wildcard. Here is a question on that topic that is explained well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588455/why-does-using-an-underscore-character-in-a-like-filter-give-me-all-the-results/19588588

Comment: I need to add the origin ids with the underscore from my table to a OR statement , so I'm trying to loop through my #invars table and put them in  to an OR statement. right now, the whole @Sql is executing multiple times:

Comment: This is how its being executed now:SELECT OrganizationId, OrigID
 FROM #Test
 
 WHERE ord.OrganizationId=@OrganizationId AND (OrigID in ('31,25,33', ',')  OR ord.LocNumOrig LIKE '31_%' 
SELECT OrganizationId, OrigID
 FROM #Test
 WHERE ord.OrganizationId=@OrganizationId AND (OrigID in('31,25,33', ',')  OR ord.LocNumOrig LIKE '31_%'  OR ord.LocNumOrig LIKE '25_%' 
SELECT OrganizationId, OrigID
 FROM #Test
 WHERE ord.OrganizationId=@OrganizationId AND (OrigID in('31,25,33', ',')  OR ord.LocNumOrig LIKE '31_%'  OR ord.LocNumOrig LIKE '25_%'  OR ord.LocNumOrig LIKE '33_%'

Comment: PLEASE stop putting details in comments. Look at how horrific that looks. I can't decipher that because comments have zero formatting. You need to explain what you are trying to accomplish clearly, not just state that this isn't working.

Comment: Sean Lange - I realize I may need to add an escape character, Im taking this a little piece at a time, right now I need my @SQl to format correctly though. As for the comments, this is my first rodeo on SO, sorry. I will remember this in the future.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? The question currently has both tags.

Comment: UPDATE: I removed the comments.

Comment: This is SQL Server. I am really close now, at least I get results but the query executes for every originID instead of one time. This is how I need it: SELECT OrganizationId,OrigID
 FROM #Test
 WHERE OrganizationId=@OrganizationId AND OrigID in ('31,25,33')  OR OrigID LIKE '31_%'  OR OrigID LIKE '33_%'  OR OrigID LIKE '25_%'

Comment: STOP putting code in the comments!!!! If you need to add details to your question you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55143451/edit) you question.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems: You can't concatenate a NULL with a string EVER; the result is always NULL (please look at the `IF @Origin IS NOT NULL` line). In your loop, you should be updating @SQL, not @SQL_2. Lastly, you should wrap ORs in parens so the logic is always explicit.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

create table #Test (OrganizationId varchar(100), OrigID varchar(50))
insert into #Test(OrganizationId,OrigID)
Values  ('5','31'),
        ('5','31_00000'),
        ('5','33'),
        ('5','33_00000'),
        ('5','25'),
        ('5','25_00000'),
        ('5','HD_00000'),
        ('5','HD')

DECLARE 
        @OrganizationId int = 5,
        @OriginId nvarchar(256) = N'31,25,33'

create table #inVars(id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, origins varchar(256))
  insert into #inVars(origins)
  Values ('31'),
         ('33'),
         ('25')

 DECLARE  @SQL           NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @ParamDefinition = N'@OrganizationId int,
                        @OriginId nvarchar(256)'


SET @SQL= 'SELECT OrganizationId,OrigID
FROM #Test
WHERE OrganizationId=@OrganizationId'

IF ISNULL(@OriginId,'') <> ''
     SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND (OrigID in (''' + @OriginId + ''') '
     DECLARE @counter INT = 1, @max INT = 0, @Origin nvarchar(50), @SQL_2 nvarchar(max)
     SELECT @max = COUNT(id) FROM #inVars
     WHILE @counter <= @max
     BEGIN
        SET @Origin = '_%'
        SET @Origin = (select origins from #invars where id = CAST(@counter as varchar(10))) + @Origin
        IF @Origin IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL_2 = N' OR OrigID LIKE ''' + @Origin + ''' '
            SET @SQL = @SQL + @SQL_2
        END
        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END
    SET @SQL=@SQL+')'
print @SQL

drop table #inVars
drop table #Test
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you want here but I think you are making it harder on yourself than you need to. There is no need to use the IN because you are also finding all values that begin with the same value. And you have hard coded the same values into your temp table. Using a string splitter this is about a million times less complicated. Just split your @OriginID on the commas and use LIKE in the join.

I am using the DelimitedSplit8k which you can find [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

I am pretty sure this should get you the information you are looking for. I would recommend avoiding loops whenever possible.

```
create table #Test (OrganizationId varchar(100), OrigID varchar(50))
insert into #Test(OrganizationId,OrigID)
Values  ('5','31'),
        ('5','31_00000'),
        ('5','33'),
        ('5','33_00000'),
        ('5','25'),
        ('5','25_00000'),
        ('5','HD_00000'),
        ('5','HD')

DECLARE 
        @OrganizationId int = 5,
        @OriginId nvarchar(256) = N'31,25,33'

select *
from #Test t
join DelimitedSplit8K(@OriginID, ',') x on t.OrigID like x.Item + '%'

drop table #Test
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.Thanks all who replied.

create table #Test (OrganizationId varchar(100), OrigID varchar(50))
insert into #Test(OrganizationId,OrigID)
Values  ('5','31'),
        ('5','31_00000'),
        ('5','33'),
        ('5','33_00000'),
        ('5','25'),
        ('5','25_00000'),
        ('5','HD_00000'),
        ('5','HD')

DECLARE 
        @OrganizationId int = 5,
        @OriginId nvarchar(256) = N'31,25,33'

create table #inVars(id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, origins varchar(256))
  insert into #inVars(origins)
  Values ('31'),
         ('33'),
         ('25')

DECLARE  @SQL           NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ParamDefinition = N'@OrganizationId int,
                        @OriginId nvarchar(256)'

```
SET @SQL= 'SELECT OrganizationId,OrigID
FROM #Test
WHERE OrganizationId=@OrganizationId'

IF ISNULL(@OriginId,'') <> ''
BEGIN
     SET @SQL = @SQL +' AND (OrigID in (''' + @OriginId + ''')) '
END

IF ISNULL(@OriginId,'') <> ''

     DECLARE @counter INT = 1, @max INT = 0, @Origin nvarchar(50), @SQL_2 nvarchar(max)
     SELECT @max = COUNT(id) FROM #inVars
     WHILE @counter <= @max
     BEGIN

        SET @Origin = (select origins from #invars where id = CAST(@counter as varchar(10)))
        SET @Origin = @Origin+'_%'
        SET @SQL_2 =  N' OR (OrigID LIKE ''' + @Origin + ''') '
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @SQL_2

        SET @counter = @counter + 1

    END
    print(@SQL)

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,@ParamDefinition,@OrganizationId,@OriginId
```

drop table #inVars
drop table #Test