# SQL--Checking for existing records which would be duplicative of a proposed record?

Tags: sql

I have a table full of existing student names and their respective .edu email addresses. When a new batch of students enters the school, I generate a "proposed" email address for each student using a standard convention (firstname_lastname@school.edu). I'm trying to craft a (single) SQL query that generates the proposed email address AND checks whether that proposal would conflict with an existing student who already has that email address.

```
SELECT firstname + '_' + lastname + '@school.edu' AS ProposedEmailAddress,

(SELECT emailaddress FROM StudentTable WHERE emailaddress LIKE firstname + '_' + lastname + '@school.edu'       ) AS DuplicateCheck

FROM StudentTable
```

Running this statement is currently producing an error ("Subquery returned more than 1 value") - which doesn't make sense to me as there should never be more than one current student with a given email address.

NOTE: Prefer solutions that are easy to understand and maintain over more elegant approaches. Thank you!

Comment: Please read ad the following link and then update your question with a concrete example (input data, expected results, etc) ; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: As an aside, you get the error message because the subquery is ***phrased*** as though it can return a set of zero to infinite rows. If you want to guarantee that it will only return one row at most, use `TOP 1` / `LIMIT 1`, or `MAX(emailaddress)`

Comment: @MatBailie In MS SQL server for example phrasing is not important, actual result is. In proposed query subquery is just not correlated and it does return entire students table anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  firstname + '_' + lastname + '@school.edu' AS ProposedEmailAddress,
  (
    SELECT MAX(emailaddress)
      FROM StudentTable 
     WHERE emailaddress = s.firstname + '_' + s.lastname + '@school.edu'
  )
    AS DuplicateCheck
FROM
  StudentTable  AS s
```

Uses MAX() to ensure a single returned values, and aliases the student table so it's no longer ambiguous (your subquery checked the email address against its own names, not the external references names).

Alternatively, if on sql server...

```
SELECT 
  s.firstname + '_' + s.lastname + '@school.edu' AS ProposedEmailAddress,
  duplicate.*
FROM
  StudentTable  AS s
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM StudentTable 
   WHERE emailaddress = s.firstname + '_' + s.lastname + '@school.edu'
)
  AS duplicate
```

Demo with both : https://dbfiddle.uk/ej0afDP0

Comment: Your first example worked -- thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `'_'` may be matching records you don't expect with `LIKE`. See teh answer here: [Why does using an Underscore character in a LIKE filter give me all the results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588455/why-does-using-an-underscore-character-in-a-like-filter-give-me-all-the-results)

Note in Necati's answer is also using `=` instead of `LIKE`. Adding table aliases may help you get results you expect.

I don't know what kind of primary key column is on your table, so I called this "PKID" below. And also, while it doesn't affect the logic, just to note, my answer has moved your [DuplicateCheck] formula out of an inlined `SELECT`, into an `APPLY`:

```
SELECT 
   T1.firstname + '_' + T1.lastname + '@school.edu' AS ProposedEmailAddress
 , DC.DuplicateCheck AS [DuplicateCheck]
FROM 
   StudentTable T1
   OUTER APPLY( SELECT TOP(1) 
         T2.emailaddress AS [DuplicateCheck]
      FROM
         StudentTable T2
      WHERE
         T2.PKID != T1.PKID AND --< don't match back to self
         T2.emailaddress = T2.firstname + '_' + T2.lastname + '@school.edu'
    ) DC
```

Using the `APPLY` will also let you add columns to the same check in `DC`. For example, if you wanted to increment "Duplicates" with a number, you could add a `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` in order to "propose a new email" in the same query. It's notable that the general design of your query is looking for student records that already exist in the same table. I would also consider if the `StudentTable` record should have an email address at time of creation/`INSERT`? And if so, you might look into table constraints, variables, and transactions.