# Escape underscore in LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using `SQL Server 2008` and I have the following stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spGetLatestLangId]
    @salt VARCHAR(50),
    @result VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @CheckStr AS VARCHAR(50)
    SET @CheckStr = @salt + '%'
    SET @result = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Lang WHERE salt LIKE @CheckStr ORDER BY dtCrt DESC)
```

Let's say my `Lang` table have following rows:

```
Id            dtCrt
------------- ----------
PRODUCT_1     2011-01-01
PRODUCT_2     2011-01-02
PRODUCTCODE_1 2011-01-05
```

When I call the stored procedure with following parameter

```
EXEC spGetLatestLangId 'PRODUCT_', @a OUTPUT
```

I'm getting `PRODUCTCODE_1` instead of `PRODUCT_2` because it ignores the `underscore`. How do I escape `underscore` in `LIKE` clause?

Comment: Try this: `LIKE 'PRODUCT[_]%'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2000/5 Escape an Underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821/sql-server-2000-5-escape-an-underscore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use:

```
SET @CheckStr = REPLACE(@salt, '_', '[_]') + '%'
```

Answer (score 4):

> how do I escape underscore in LIKE clause

Using the `ESCAPE` clause:

```
where some_column LIKE 'X/_%' ESCAPE '/';
```

in your case:

```
WHERE salt LIKE @CheckStr ESCAPE '/'
```

You can use *any* character for the escape character (e.g. `ESCAPE '\'` or `ESCAPE '@'`) - it's a good idea to use one that is not part of the values.

But this means you also have to call the procedure with the escape character:

```
EXEC spGetLatestLangId 'PRODUCT/_', @a OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets. The table shows several examples of using the LIKE keyword and the [ ] wildcard characters.

For your case:

> `... LIKE 'PRODUCT[_]%'`

Answer (score 1):

_ is a wildcard in SQL Server. You can add a regex pattern to your String. Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(strings nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #temp(strings)
VALUES(N'PRODUCT_1'),(N'PRODUCT_2'),(N'PRODUCTCODE_1')

SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE strings LIKE N'PRODUCT[_]%'

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql server keywords and wildcard characters are used as normal words by enclosing in `[]`

```
eg:- select * from [User]

     select * from [User] where name like 'John[_]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Lang WHERE salt LIKE REPLACE(@CheckStr, '_', '[_]')  ORDER BY dtCrt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap 
`'_' -> '[_]'`

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spGetLatestLangId]
    @salt VARCHAR(50),
    @result VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @CheckStr AS VARCHAR(50)
    SET @CheckStr = @salt + '%'
    SET @result = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Lang WHERE salt LIKE REPLACE(@CheckStr,'_','[_]') ORDER BY dtCrt DESC)
```