# SQL server - Find a string which starts with a specific value and ends with a value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am looking for a code which can search a specific column, that always start with a value (ukinvoice) and ends with a numeric value which is greater than 00030
e.g. ukinvoice1245345.inv.1245788945.3.00030

Comment: what data type is this column? String or Numeric?

Comment: It a [Varchar] data type

Answer (score 0):

Search for a string with the 'like' operator and the % wildcard.
Cast the last part of the string to an integer and work with numbers.

```
SELECT *  
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like 'prefix%'
  AND CAST(SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME, (LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) - 4) , 5) AS INT) > 30;
```

In writing:

- Search for all strings with the correct prefix
- Search the last prefix >> convert to a number >> make sure that the value is greater than your wanted value

Remark: MySQL uses a CONVERT function, instead of CAST

Good Luck!

Comment: Just take caution if either the prefix or postfix contain any `LIKE` especial characters, there must be escaped: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5821/2557263

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, but I am looking for an expression where the Prefix is always "ukinvoice" and Postfix always greater than 00030. So i can use this expression to calculate other values in my query

Comment: Hi Satya, I indeed overlooked that part and added an update. good luck!