# C# check string contain a word with underscores

Tags: c#, string, nhibernate, contains, linq-to-nhibernate

I want to get all items which contain "**_AT_**" or "**PV_**", 
but `d.Nom.Contains($"PV_")` and `d.Nom.Contains($"_AT_")` gets also items containing only "AT" and "PV"

```
 IQueryable<DocumentMetadata> docPV = NHibernateSession.Current.Query<DocumentMetadata>()
           .Where(d => d.IdEntiteRattachement == missionId
                       && d.Nom.Contains($"PV_")
                       && d.Desactive == false)
           .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateDerniereModif);

        IList<DocumentMetadata> docAR = NHibernateSession.Current.Query<DocumentMetadata>()
           .Where(d => d.IdEntiteRattachement == missionId
                       && d.Nom.Contains($"_AT_")
                       && d.Desactive == false)
           .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateDerniereModif).ToList();
```

Comment: `&& (d.Nom.Contains($"PV_") || d.Nom.Contains($"_AT_"))`?

Comment: Are you asking how to combine those conditions? As in `&& (d.Nom.Contains($"PV_") || d.Nom.Contains($"_AT_"))`

Comment: In SQL, underscore (and percent) are wild cards. You have to escape them. You most probably will find that in the docs.

Comment: Is it because the underscore is acting as a wildcard? Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821/sql-server-escape-an-underscore? (i.e. d.Nom.Contains(@"PV\_") - Note you need '@' because \ is an escape char itself.

Comment: Don't close this question for being unclear. IMHO, it's an clear question: filtering for `Contains("_AT_")` also finds strings that only contain `"AT"`. (However it may be a duplicate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, underscore (and percent) are wild cards. NHibernate doesn't automatically escape them, because you can make use of them. Behind `.Contains`, there is SQL's `LIKE`.

Escaping wildcards depend on the underlying DBMS.

Try this:

```
d.Nom.Contains("\\_AT\\_")
```

(It may not work. See the docs of your database engine.)

Comment: or `.Contains(@"\_AT\_")`

Comment: I test those 2 codes, but they do not work. Then I use `Nom.Replace("_","|").Contains("PV|")`

Comment: Sounds like a working solution. However,  it has two draw backs: You cannot distinguish between "PV_" and "PV|", and the database won't use indexes. When a database runs a `LIKE`, it usually cannot use indexes anyway. But there may be special optimizations e.g. when using `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`. It depends on the database. What database do you use?

Comment: For many common databases, it often CAN use indexes (for some of the work) for LIKE, assuming that the pattern contains a non-wildcard initial part.

Comment: @OskarBerggren: Yes, that's why I say `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow none of the solutions given above would escape the underscore properly (I tried `\\_ @\_ [_] $_ ^_`) so I ended up filtering again in pure LINQ:

```
var list = dc.Employees.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(partial)).ToList();
if (partial.Contains("_")) // underscore is an sql wildcard character and will match anything, so filter again in .NET linq
    list = list.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(partial)).ToList();
```

This is obviously not the best solution since it retrieves a bigger amount of rows from the DB than necessary and filters again in memory, but in my case the overhead is acceptable.