# Filtering for a specific character in the middle of a reference - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

Folks, I am trying to create a query to identify orders that have specific reference number or alpha character _.

This query is returning results, but also is showing some other like results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    O.ordernumber, R.refnumber 'PO Reference', I.invstatus 'InvoicStatus',
    O.ord_invoicestatus
FROM 
    reference R 
INNER JOIN 
    order O ON R.ordernumber = O.ordernumber
LEFT JOIN 
    invoice I ON I.ordernumber = O.ordernumber
WHERE 
    R.ref_num LIKE '%X_%'
    AND R.reftype = 'PO' 
    AND o.obillto LIKE 'LO%'
ORDER BY 
    2
```

The highlighted part in the screenshot is what I don't want to find in my result set.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Underscore is a wildcard character in TSQL, similar to % but only for one character.

You'll have to escape the underscore, [SQL Server Escape an Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821/sql-server-escape-an-underscore) is similar with some examples.

Comment: Thank you. Just what i was looking for:  LIKE '%[_]%'

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
WHERE 
    R.ref_num LIKE '%X_%'
```

To

```
WHERE 
    R.ref_num LIKE '%X[_]%'
```