# SQL Like operator not working if underscore at first char

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not getting the exact record if string has underscore is a first char
Example:

```
declare @name nvarchar(max)
set @name='_#@#_1'
SELECT Name from Emp where Name like  @name + '%'
```

Expected Output: It should return a single row as per table records (_#@#_123)
but returning below records

```
_#@#_123
@#@#@123
@#@#_123
_#@#_123
```

Comment: Pease refer to [Using Wildcard Characters As Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals)

Comment: Thank you.
But I will not have always a underscore as first char

Comment: The underscore is the wildcard for a single character so basically the results you showed match your searchstring...

Comment: Thank you Tyron78.
But the 4  results are unique.
I want only the matching record starting with all the chars

Comment: @Jethij yes, I understood - therefore please have a look at my answer: I would suggest using substring and = instead of `LIKE` in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821/sql-server-escape-an-underscore

Answer (score 3):

Since underscore is a special character, you'll have to escape it using the character of your choice. Let's use a backslash `\`. You'll have to both 1) escape it in your data and 2) add the `ESCAPE` clause:

```
declare @name nvarchar(max)
set @name='_#@#_1'
SELECT Name from Emp where Name like 
  replace(replace(@name, '\', '\\'), '_', '\_') + '%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: And for the case the escape character itself can occur in the strings, escape that as well: `replace(replace(@name, '\', '\\'), '_', '\_')`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the result of your query is correct since the underscore is the wildcard for a single character. However, you might want to try the following which basically does the same as your `LIKE ... + '%'`:

```
SELECT Name
  FROM(SELECT Name
         FROM @Emp
         WHERE LEN(Name) >= LEN(@name)
      ) X
   WHERE SUBSTRING(Name, 1, LEN(@name)) = @name
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap underscore using brackets:

```
CREATE TABLE [Emp] (
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO [Emp] ([Name]) VALUES
(N'_#@#_123'),
(N'@#@#@123'),
(N'@#@#_123'),
(N'_#@#_123')

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX) = '_#@#_1'

--SELECT [Name] FROM [Emp] WHERE [Name] LIKE @name + '%' -- not working as expected
SELECT [Name] FROM [Emp] WHERE [Name] LIKE REPLACE(@name, '_', '[_]') + '%' -- OK
```

[Try working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HRlpINhs)